# SwiftUI: Change param using call back

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am looking at how I can change a param using a call back.

```
struct MainView: View {
  
  @State var name = "Original Name"
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 16) {
      FirstView(doChangeName: self.changeName)
      Text(name)
    }
    .padding(32)
  }
  
  func changeName() {
    print("Changing Name")
    self.name = "Another Name"
  }
  
}

struct FirstView : View {
  var doChangeName : () -> ()
  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
      let newName = "New Name"
      self.doChangeName()
      
    }) { Text("Change Name") }
  }
}
```

When I click on change name button, it will be change to "Another Name".  How can it be a param derived from a child view and in this case variable newName done through call back.

In another words, pass the newName variable back to function changeName.

Comment: Use binding instead of callback

Comment: @RajaKishan, yes we commonly use binding which I know.  What if I need to use callback?

Comment: What would be meaning **params** in your question?

Comment: @swiftPunk name to newName from the button click in FirstView which is a subview.

Comment: @DarylWong: it seems having changeName function is useless and also you are returning a newValue without taking use of oldValue! Your coding could be done in better way, but where you are using this codes? use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily with binding but as you mention you want to use a closure with param.

Change closure syntax.

```
struct MainView: View {
    
    @State var name = "Original Name"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 16) {
            FirstView(doChangeName: self.changeName)
            Text(name)
        }
        .padding(32)
    }
    
    func changeName(_ name: String) { // <== Here
        print("Changing Name")
        self.name = name
    }
    
}

struct FirstView : View {
    var doChangeName : (String) -> () // <== Here
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.doChangeName("New Name")
            
        }) { Text("Change Name") }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, this is what I need